# [Environment]::Exit(0) required, but how can I use a script with Invoke-Expression with that?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

It seems that I am in the powers`hell` with exit codes.

There are many topics about why powershell behaves weird with its exit codes (for syntax errors, etc).
There is furthermore a big issue with exit codes and the `Parameter` attribute. e.g.
calling a script with the following code

```
Param(
  [Parameter()]$a
)
exit 9999
```

returns an exit code of **0** in cmd.exe (e.g. `echo %ERRORLEVEL%`) making it impossible to properly deal with return codes.

The very last workaround for that is using Environment::Exit:

```
Param(
  [Parameter()]$a
)
[Environment]::Exit(9999)
```

---

Now the problem: I've written a script that has extensive `Param` definitions and therefore needs `Environment::Exit` to work.
This utility returns a value via echo, here is a working script for that

```
# dummy.ps1
Param(
  [Parameter()]$a
)

echo "foo 42"

[Environment]::Exit(10)
```

Of course I don't need the exit here, but the real-world script requires this to properly exit after the `echo` indicating exit code **10** in both `ps` and in `cmd`

Calling it via `powershell -f dummy.ps1` returns 42, everything is fine.

But here is the problem: I want to reuse this script in another script so I can use the echoed value properly.

When I am in the powershell prompt I want to do something like that:

```
$res = Invoke-Expression "& d:\dummy.ps1"
echo $res
```

But Environment::Exit closes my prompt after the Invoke-Expression and everything is gone.
(Even if I put this code in a separate `ps1` file)

Is there a scenario in which this entire thing works as expected?
Again: I need proper exit codes for `ps` and `cmd` so `exit 10` or `exit(10)` fail here. And due to the behaviour with `[Parameter()]` no other exit code than Environment::Exit does work.

Comment: Rule of thumb for when you encounter an error state inside your script/cmdlet/function; never `exit()` always `throw`. If you need total control over the final exit code, wrap your script in a caller script that calls `[Environment]::Exit()`

Comment: Please show complete example where `exit` does not work properly. It work well for me. I type three commands in CMD prompt: `echo param([Parameter()]$a)exit 9999 > Test.ps1`, `powershell -File Test.ps1`, `echo %errorlevel%` and last one print 9999. And do not use `[Environment]::Exit` it does not terminate host gracefully. For example, ISE will not ask you about unsaved files. Use `$Host.SetShouldExit` instead.

Comment: @PetSerAl your repro case is exactly my issue. As the tag suggests: Are you teasting it with powershell version 2? `powershell $PSVersionTable` returns PSVersion 2.0 for me. I am on a Windows 7 machine. This behaviour might have changed in later versions.

Comment: Try this as workaround: `powershell -Command ".\Test.ps1;exit $LastExitCode"`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing the same thing - in order to recreate the issue, execute with powershell.exe -version 2.0  -file blah.ps1

It's version 2.0...   and parameter.  once you drop the [Parameter()] you get exit codes as expected.
Param(
    #[Parameter(ParameterSetName="inst")][string]$inst
    [string]$inst
)
so, this works - swap out the commented lines, then you always get an exit code of 0...  And for someone to post, you should never use EXIT?  dude, we all have different requirements..

I guess my work around is to not use parameter and just do it this way - I have to get this to work consistently on various OS versions which means I have a minimum requirement that it must work on 2.0.